# Access members of data member array in jquery template

Tags: jquery, json, templates

So I have a JSON object that is basically organized like this(syntax is probably wrong, but I think it gets the general idea across):

```
var result = {{Name: 'name1', Type: 'type1', UserInfo: [{date:'123', location: 'earth'}]},
         {Name: 'name2', Type: 'type2', UserInfo: [{date:'456', location: 'mars'}]}};
```

I want to access the members inside the UserInfo array inside of a jQuery template, but everything I try results in a not found or undefined error for the member I am trying to access.

For example:

```
${UserInfo.date}

${$UserInfo.date}

${$item.UserInfo.date}
```

Can anyone tell me how to access those array members?

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need jQuery to work with JSON.  JSON is associated with JavaScript (JavaScript Object Notation).

To access an object in JSON, try this:

```
var innerArray = result[0].UserInfo;
```

This will get the UserInfo array from the first object in result

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't need jQuery if I just wanted to access the data, but I want to bind the result array to a jQuery template for display. That's the context I am having trouble with. I guess a clearer description is needed.
Template:
${Name}   <--this works
${UserInfo} <-- returns [object Object]
${UserInfo.location} <-- throws error.

I need to access the location.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax should be:

```
var result = [
  {"Name": "name1", "Type": "type1", "UserInfo": {"date":"123", "location": "earth"}},
  {"Name": "name2", "Type": "type2", "UserInfo": {"date":"456", "location": "mars"}}
];
```

You can access it like this:

```
alert(result[1].UserInfo.date); //"456"
```

This also works:

```
alert(result[1]['UserInfo']['date']); //"456"
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/q837w/).

Comment: Again, the context in which I am trying to access the array members is a jQuery template, not plain javascript.

Comment: What exactly does jQuery have to do with it?

Comment: You said `${UserInfo}` returns an object, try `${UserInfo}.location`

Comment: jQuery templates: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ .

${UserInfo}.location returns [object Object].location as text. You need to use the template notation to access any data members which is the reason for all the {} and $. I found this:jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uZzZk and that works as long as the variable 'd' does not have var in front. I've been trying to figure what the difference is between that and my object. Mine is return from a WCF web service and I pass it to the template as data.FunctionNameResult.

Comment: Hmm it seems it's not a good idea to use that plugin, it says it's not going to be maintained on the page you just linked.

Comment: That is true about the plugin, but it's also the most complete template library that I have found. Everything else seems to be in pre beta or something. And honestly, I don't need it to be maintained, I am deploying my system with its own copy of the template library.